# Is only one in seven medical interventions supported by reliable scientific evidence?

Tags: medical-science

My macroeconomics professor claimed

> According to one researcher, only one in seven medical interventions is supported by reliable scientific evidence.

A quick Google search shows the quote from the book *[Macroeconomics: A Contemporary Approach](https://books.google.com/books?id=oLr8QGdoCG4C&pg=PA95&lpg=PA95&dq=one%20in%20seven%20medical%20interventions%20is%20supported%20by%20reliable%20scientific%20evidence&source=bl&ots=VJG0HTLt-f&sig=9k4rtgjZduEceOpQws2p77z2SLc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=nrCuVKukG4mpyATOkIHICA&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=one%20in%20seven%20medical%20interventions%20is%20supported%20by%20reliable%20scientific%20evidence&f=false)*. However, the book just refers to another source. Is this claim actually verifiable?

Comment: For the benefit of use casual readers, what exactly do you mean by "medical interventions"

Comment: The "another source" cited in the book is [this article](http://www.albany.edu/~scifraud/data/sci_fraud_3602.html) which says, "That assumption is so far off the mark that the term "medical science" is
practically an oxymoron. **Dr. David Eddy of the Jackson Hole Group has estimated that no more
than 15 percent of medical interventions are supported by reliable scientific evidence**. ... "It's
more of an art form than a science form," he said. ... Because of individual variations among patients and physicians, clinical
medicine will always be in large measure an art, and that is a good thing."

Comment: The example of "not scientific" given in the book is that "nobody really knows" how acetaminophen works.